# Third homotopy group of quotient space

Tags: lie-groups, compactness, homotopy-theory, connectedness, quotient-spaces

The third [homotopy group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group) $\pi_3(G)$ of a compact connected simple [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) $G$ is

$$\pi_3(G)=Z.$$

What if $G$ is not a Lie group but a [quotient space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) of two Lie groups, $G/H$?

I know that if a space is compact, then so are all its quotient spaces. Moreover, if a space is connected, then so are all its quotient spaces. Does this mean that if $G$ is a compact connected simple Lie group with $\pi_3(G)=Z$, then $\pi_3(G/H)=Z$ is also given?

*Edit in response to the comment by Arnaud Mortier:*

I am especially interested in the case where $G$ is a *direct product of two simple Lie groups $G'$*, such as $G= G'\times G' = SU(3)\times SU(3)$. Algebraically, the [special unitary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group) $SU(3)$ is a simple Lie group, meaning that its Lie algebra is simple. We know that $\pi_3(SU(3))=Z$. Let us consider the exemplary case where $H=SU(2)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$. Do we get

$$\pi_3(G/H)=\pi_3(G)=\pi_3(SU(3)\times SU(3))=\pi_3(SU(3))\times\pi_3(SU(3))=Z\times Z?$$

Comment: Since $G$ is simple it doesn't have non-trivial quotients. Your $G'$ is not simple.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier It can have a quotient space: $G/H$ is the set of all cosets $gH$ with the quotient topology. It may not be a group of course.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Looking at the relevant part of the long exact sequence on homotopy groups, we have an exact sequence $$\pi_3(H)\to\pi_3(G)\to \pi_3(G/H)\to \pi_2(H).$$  Since $\pi_2(H)$ is trivial ($\pi_2$ of any Lie group is trivial), this means $\pi_3(G/H)$ will be isomorphic to $\pi_3(G)$ iff the image of $\pi_3(H)$ in $\pi_3(G)$ is trivial.  So for instance, taking $G=SU(3)$ and $H=SU(2)$, $\pi_3(H)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and the map $\pi_3(H)\to \pi_3(G)$ is an isomorphism, so $\pi_3(G/H)$ will be trivial rather than $\mathbb{Z}$ (in fact $G/H\cong S^5$ in that case since $H$ is exactly the stabilizer of a point in the usual action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$, so the quotient is the orbit of a point which is $S^5$).

Comment: To be more precise, "if and only if the image of $\pi_3(H)$ in $\pi_3(G)$ is trivial".

Answer (score 1):

Eric's answer is fine, but a bit more can be said.  Mainly, it is very rare for $\pi_3(G/H)$ to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$!

> **Proposition:**  Suppose $H\subseteq G$ are compact Lie groups and $H$ is non-abelian.  Then $\pi_3(G/H)$  has smaller rank than $\pi_3(G)$.

In particular, if $G$ is simple and $H$ is non-abelian, then $\pi_3(G/H)$ is a finite cyclic group.  (On the other hand, if $H$ is abelian, then the long exact sequence in Eric's answer shows that $\pi_3(G/H)$ is canonically isomorphic to $\pi_3(G)$.)

So, why is the proposition true?  The key term in the Dynkin index (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90124/3rd-homotopy-group-of-a-compact-simple-lie-group).

In more detail, the universal cover of $H$ splits as $\mathbb{R}^n\times H_1\times ... \times H_k$ where each $H_i$ is a compact simply connected simple Lie group.  The assumption that $H$ is non-abelian implies that $k\geq 1$.  Consider the induced map $H_1\rightarrow H\rightarrow G$ where the first map is the restriction of the covering projection to $H_1$.  Since $H_1$ is simple, this gives an induced map $\mathbb{Z}\cong \pi_3(H)\rightarrow \pi_3(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}^s$, where $s$ is the number of (non-abelian) simple factors in the universal cover of $G$.  If this map is non-trivial, it follows that the map $\pi_3(H)\rightarrow \pi_3(G)$ is non-trivial, which would then prove the proposition.

But why is this map non-trivial?  Well, the map on $\pi_3$ induced by an inclusion of a simple Lie group into another simple group is known as they Dynkin Index.  It can be computed in terms of the restriction of the Killing form on $G$ to that of $H$, an in particular, is known to always be a positive integer.